# Adding Animation To Dropdown Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

My dropdown menu currently works but how can I'd like to accomplish two more things with it:

1. Add animation (Either CSS or JS)
2. The dropdown should not push contents below it down

Here's [the codpen](https://codepen.io/ericnguyen23/pen/EBrodo?editors=0110) and some snippet code:

HTML

```
<li>
          <a>Products</a>

          <div className="subnav-block">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a>Product A</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a>Product B</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
```

CSS

```
.subnav-block {
  position: static;
  width: 100% !important;
  top: 54px;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px 0 !important;
  display: none;
  height: 80px;
  background: gray;
}

.nav:hover > li > .subnav-block {
   display: block;
}
```

Comment: nothing happens when I hover or click the nav items in your codepen

Comment: “Add animation” is a rather large topic. I would suggest you read up about css animation or try to find something close to what you want.

Comment: Also consider using `position: absolute` if you don’t want it to push content down.

Comment: There is no such HTML attribute as `className`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you using `display:none` it create problem in transition so it is better to use `opacity:0;` and `visibility:hidden;` instated of the `display:none;`. and 
 if you do not want to The drop down  push contents below it down then use `position:absolute;` instead of `position:static;`

this css work for me so also add this css in your existing css file:

```
.nav li {
  list-style: none;
  position:relative;
}    
.subnav-block {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100% !important;
  top: 54px;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px 0 !important;
  height: 140px;
  background: gray;
  opacity:0;
  visibillity:hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out 0.15s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out 0.15s;
  -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out 0.15s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out 0.15s;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out 0.15s;
}

.nav > li:hover .subnav-block{
  opacity:1;
  visibilty:visiable;
}
```

thank you

Comment: This works. The only thing I changed is .nav:hover since I wanted to show the all subnav items.

Comment: you can replace .nav > li:hover .subnav-block{
  opacity:1;
  visibilty:visiable;
}   By .nav:hover .subnav-block{
  opacity:1;
  visibilty:visiable;
}  to get your result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css property position: absolute to accomplish your target, and here what you will do

```
<li class="nav-item">
          <a>Products</a>

          <div className="subnav-block">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a>Product A</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a>Product B</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
```

and here is the css

```
.nav-item{
position: relative;
}
        .subnav-block{
           position: absolute;
           min-width: 215px /* or any width fits your idea */
           top: 100%;
           padding: .5rem 1rem;
           background: #fff;
           box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.18);
           transition: all .3s;
           opacity: 0;
           visibility: hidden;
           transform: translateY(10px); /* i choosed translate for animation, you can choose what you prefer */
        }
    .nav-item:hover .subnav-block{
        opacity: 1;
        visibility
        transform: translateY(0)
    }
```

read more about transform on [w3school css transform](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp)